# Dedup.sys 0x7E after inplace upgrade Server 2016 => 19

Tags: windows-server-2019, bsod, deduplication

I've recently performed an in-place upgrade from Server 2016 => 2019 (non-domain).

2 of the drives connected has been configured with data deduplication (mostly VHDs for Hyper-V). Ever since the upgrade, attempting to access, reverse dedupe (start-dedupejob -type unoptimize) the system will crash with 0x07E dedup.sys

(0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000094, 0xFFFFF80BE9E82F29, 0xFFFFA00F5D4BA3E8, 0xFFFFA00F5D4B9C30)))

Attempting to copy the data off the drive results in the same error. I have spun up a 2016 VM in an attempt to copy/reverse dedupe and it fails stating revision is unknown. Spun up a fresh 2019 to do the same and receive the same bugcheck as the upgraded system.

Hindsight being 20/20 I should've checked these things before the upgrade but now I'm in this situation, are there any suggestions? I've tried googling for the past several hours and have only come across [one report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/424621/bsod-dedupsys-after-inplace-upgrade-server2016-201.html) of the same, with no solutions provided.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Q&A Website there is a notice that this is a know bug and will be fixed in this month's Preview Update (Jul 13) When published it will be under KB5004244 for Server 2019. [ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/424621/bsod-dedupsys-after-inplace-upgrade-server2016-201.html)

I hope the reference is not fake as it seems there are a lot of people with the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, I originally posted into that thread, glad it's been identified as a bug and is being resolved. Appreciate the reference!